# Why does javascript replace only first instance when using replace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this

```
 var date = $('#Date').val();
```

this get the value in the textbox what would look like this

12/31/2009

Now I do this on it

```
var id = 'c_' + date.replace("/", '');
```

and the result is

c_1231/2009

It misses the last '/' I don't understand why though.

Comment: This is so painful and unnecessary. I wonder what reason there was to implement `replace` like this. I even choose `str.split(search).join(replacement)` over the regexp.

Comment: Update: there is a proposal to add `String.prototype.replaceAll` to the standard: https://2ality.com/2019/12/string-prototype-replaceall.html

Comment: @ColeTobin no implemented in all major browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility

Comment: @jave.web now implemented in all major browsers. This is so simple : just `date.replaceAll('/','')`

Comment: @matanh that's great news! even included in https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll :-)

Answer (score 311, accepted):

You need to set the [*g* flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) to replace globally:

```
date.replace(new RegExp("/", "g"), '')
// or
date.replace(/\//g, '')
```

Otherwise only the first occurrence will be replaced.

Comment: Why difference then C# replace. Thought it would replace all occurrences by default. But why did it take 2 slashes away if it is only first occurrence?

Comment: @chobo2 it didn't take away two slashes. There were only two to begin with, and it removed the first one.

Comment: @chobo2: Well, JavaScript is not C#. And `12/31/2009` does only contain two slashes.

Comment: Perhaps the most informative comment I've seen regarding Regular Expressions!

Answer (score 84):

Unlike the C#/.NET class library (and most other sensible languages), when you pass a `String` in as the string-to-match argument to the `string.replace` method, it doesn't do a string replace. It converts the string to a `RegExp` and does a regex substitution. As Gumbo explains, a regex substitution requires the `g`‍lobal flag, which is not on by default, to replace all matches in one go.

If you want a real string-based replace — for example because the match-string is dynamic and might contain characters that have a special meaning in regexen — the JavaScript idiom for that is:

```
var id= 'c_'+date.split('/').join('');
```

Comment: If you wanted to really push this kind of functionality, you might try something like `String.prototype.strReplace = function(needle, replacement) {return this.split(needle).join(replacement||"");};` Then you could `var id = "c_" + date.strReplace("/")`

Comment: I like the explanation in this better than any other answers to similar questions. The accepted answer only provides a workaround, not an answer to 'Why' as in the title.

Comment: This only seems to work on the first two instances of my search string... all others are ignored...?? (Does it mater that my search instance has multiple characters?

Comment: @bobince, this doesn't seem to be the case: "It converts the string to a RegExp and does a regex substitution." Look at these: `"abc".replace("^a", "_")` » `"abc"` and `"abc".replace(new RegExp("^a"), "_")` » `"_bc"`

Comment: @tomekwi Part of converting a string to a regex would involve escaping special characters.

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace) {
if (replace === undefined) {
    return this.toString();
}
return this.split(search).join(replace);
}
```

Comment: Now String has an officially supported [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) function.