# How can i replace text inside variable with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does javascript replace only first instance when using replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967119/why-does-javascript-replace-only-first-instance-when-using-replace)

I have this variable

```
var newRow = "<td><div> [[myvar]]</div> <div> [[myvar]]</div> </td> "
```

When i do this

```
newRow  = newRow.replace('[[myvar]]', '10');
```

Only first occurance gets replaced and not the second

Comment: See [this][1] answer. That is almost the same question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967119/why-does-javascript-replace-only-first-instance-when-using-replace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might use a regular expression

```
newRow  = newRow.replace(/\[\[myvar\]\]/g, '10');
```

There is no other simple solution for multiple replacements. Note that :

- regex are heavily optimised on all browsers, especially if using the `/\[\[myvar\]\]/` notation
- if your pattern is dynamic you may use `new RegExp(somepattern, 'g')` (but [for better performances don't use this if you have a fixed pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FObjects%2FRegExp))

Comment: i don't understood , if i have exact match , why do i need to have regex. i mean function replace is same why regex works but not simple string

Comment: In Javascript the replace function is actually based on regex. By default the replace hits only the first occurrance. The `g` flag set the global match option.

Comment: thanks buddy. i don't know when i see regex , i heart starts pumping faster like i saw tiger in front of me

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
newRow = newRow.replace(new RegExp('[[myvar]]', 'g'), '10');
```