# why does str.replace() only replace the first found item?

Tags: javascript, replace

```
text = "1/2/3"
result = text.replace("/", "");
```

I expect the result to be "123" but instead it's "12/3"
Why?

Comment: This is a good answer:
[Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1144788/3088045)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does javascript replace only first instance when using replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967119/why-does-javascript-replace-only-first-instance-when-using-replace)

Comment: @Kamafeather Thx, just looked at it, and it's exactly what I needed

Comment: Voted to close my own question, since it is, indeed, a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the global selection "g" flag and use a regex instead of a string in first parameter.

```
result = text.replace(/\//g, "");
```

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yep true, was about to point to that in the answer. Thanks

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti what does "regex parameter" mean?

Comment: @zerkms poorly worded but _"where first parameter (pattern) is a regex"_.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regular expression as argument to replace with global selection.

```
"1/2/3".replace(/\//g, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below Regexp

```
"1/2/3".replace(/\//g,"");
```

This will replace all the `/` elements with `""`.

Comment: In what is this different/better compared to Ahmad, Vishwanath and Felipe answers?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing the same:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(matchStr, replaceStr) {
  return this.replace(new RegExp(matchStr, 'g'), replaceStr);
 };
var str = "1/2/3";
result = str.replaceAll('/', '');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = "1/2/3"
a =a.split("/").join("")
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding the use of regex and for improved perf

Comment: @Kaiido: "and for improved perf" --- why do you think so? It allocates an additional array.

Comment: @zerkms http://jsperf.com/replace-all-vs-split-join from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1145525/3702797