# Make parseFloat convert variables with commas into numbers

Tags: javascript, function, parsefloat

I'm trying to get parseFloat to convert a `userInput` (`prompt`) into a number.

For example:

```
var userInput = prompt("A number","5,000") 
function parse_float(number) {
    return parseFloat(number)
}
```

When `userInput = 5,000`, `parse_Float(userInput)` returns `5`.

However, if the user was inputting a value to change something else (ie: make a bank deposit or withdrawl) Then I to work properly, `parse.Float(userInput)` needs to return `5000`, not `5`.
If anyone could tell me how to do this it would help me so much. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may sound stupid, but why don't you get rid of the commas with a simple str.replace ?

Comment: Like @Bonatoc said - `parseInt("5,100".replace(",",""));`

Comment: Careful though, if your app needs i18n, cents ponctuations (decimal marks) differ from country to country : http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Decimal_mark#/Examples_of_use

Comment: I totally wrote that wrong, but thanks anyway

Comment: `replace(/,/g, '')`: [Why does javascript replace only first instance when using replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1967119/218196)

Comment: @wyattbergeron1 Yeah that's javascript it replaces the first occurrence only, here is how to do it for all: `"567,763,321".replace(/,/g,"");`

Comment: What is the syntax `parse.Float` supposed to do?

Comment: @Bonatoc It's currently a 'game' that i'm working on. It says in the beginning that it will use U.S. standard measurements punctuation etc.

Comment: @wyattbergeron1 Does your program also accept commas in the wrong place? For example, do `5,0,0,0` and `,,,5000,,,` parse as `5000` as well?

Comment: @lambdaFairy no, it doesn't Ill figure that out,  thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov That code won't change it if the commas are in the wrong spot. for example, 5,6,7,7,6,3,321 any idea how to fix that?

Comment: It occurred to me that you've only used integers so far, but call `parseFloat`. Do you want to accept decimal points as well? If not, `parseInt` is better.

Comment: @LambdaFairy it's set to acccept decimals too, but it automatically accepts them. Only reason I don't use parseInt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is close, but not quite right.

[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) doesn't change the original string; it creates a new one. So you need to create a variable to hold the new string, and call `parseFloat` on that.

Here's the fixed code:

```
function parseFloatIgnoreCommas(number) {
    var numberNoCommas = number.replace(/,/g, '');
    return parseFloat(numberNoCommas);
}
```

I also renamed the function to `parseFloatIgnoreCommas`, which better describes what it does.

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives me what js default does, the first instance. If you find a way to fix this, edit this and/or tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally tried to parse the original string rather than the new one. The code should work now.

Answer (score 2):

This is the function I use to scrub my user inputted numbers from a form. It handles anything a user may put in with a number like $ or just accidentally hitting a key.

I copied the following out of an object:

```
cleanInput : function(userValue){
    //clean the user input and scrub out non numerals
    var cleanValue = parseFloat(userValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));    
    return cleanValue;
},
```

To make it non-object just change the first line to `cleanInput(){....`

Answer (score 0):

I have put together info from the comments to form a basic answer:

The answer seems to simply be to set parse_float to run :

```
number.replace(/,/g, "")
return parseFloat(number)
```

The complete code would look like this:

```
var userInput = prompt("A number","523,000,321,312,321") 
function parse_float(number) {
    number.replace(/,/g, "")
return parseFloat(number)
}
```

returns: `523000321312321`