# I want to replace a text to an specific image

Tags: image, text, replace

I want to create **emojis** on my website so where ever is 
**:D found to replace it with an image**

Comment: This will require JavaScript or (preferably) jQuery. Have you  made any attempts at solving this yourself or searching online?

Answer (score 0):

Use could take the hole Content and use php with str_replace(':D','', $content);

Answer (score 0):

You could right a javascript that loops through all eligible elements and regex through the innerHTML of the element (or even a simple indexOf would work). then swap out the html with your new element. could be a simple inline image.

JQuery could help you traverse through the elements. this is a very crude example would need cleanup but I think you can understand whats happening

```
<html>
<head>
    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        div.smile {
            display:inline;
            background: url(http://pix.iemoji.com/sbemojix2/0742.png) no-repeat;
            background-size: 16px 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span>hello :D</span>
    <div>hello :D</div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Hello
            </td>
            <td>:D</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="text" value ="hello :D"/>

    <script>
        $('div, span, td').each(function(i,e){
            if(e.innerHTML.indexOf(':D')>=0)
                e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(':D','<div class="smile">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

hope this helps

Comment: It helped me a lot, but when there is more then 1 emoji it replaces just the first one, btw i change the code so it looks this like:
<script>
        $('div, textarea').each(function(i,e){
            if(e.innerHTML.indexOf(':D')>=0)
                e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(':D','<img src="./img/smiley.png">');
        });
</script>

Comment: Hey Hamza, the standard replace functionality replaces only the first occurrence. Here is an article that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967119/why-does-javascript-replace-only-first-instance-when-using-replace   Hope this helps

Comment: I solved it using this

$body = $row['body'];

$body = str_replace(":D","<img src='img/smiley.png'>",$body);