# Replace all words in string with new HTML strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace a string like:

```
var str = "@xxx test@xxx.com"
```

by a new string contains HTML like:

```
<a href>@xxx</a> test@xxx.com
```

I tried to this way to replace but not correct:

```
str = str.replace(/@xxx/g, "<a href>@xxx</a>")
```

With this way, it will return HTML like:

```
<a href>@xxx</a> test<a href>@xxx</a>.com
```

I just want to replace whole word "@xxx". How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does javascript replace only first instance when using replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967119/why-does-javascript-replace-only-first-instance-when-using-replace)

Comment: well, my question is different

Comment: The other question includes the answer to this question: simply remove the g flag to not do a global replace.

Comment: I really need to do a global replace all the word "@xxx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
alert("@xxx test@xxx.com @xxx @xxx".replace(/(\B@xxx)/g, "<a href>$1</a>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's just keep it nice and clean....

```
var string = '@xxx test@xxx.com',
regger = /(@\S+)\s(.+.com)/,
output = string.replace(regger,"<a href='$1'>$2</a>")
```

[Sample](https://regex101.com/r/lQ3rF9/1)

Comment: Downvoting people providing you with answers, let alone correct answers, isn't very nice.