# replace symbol with space jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want replace the symbol "_" with a space in a div class,

this is a example :

```
<div class="textreply">

my_names_is_mark

</div>
```

i want replace with this :

```
 <div class="textreply">

    my names is mark

</div>
```

i have already build 2 script like this :

1:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".textreply").text(function () {
    return jQuery(this).text().replace("_", "  "); 
});          });
```

2:

```
$('.textreply').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('_', ' ')); 
});
```

the problem with this 2 script is to replaced only the first "_" of word

example this :

```
my names_is_mark
```

and not continue .

how replace every "_" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does javascript replace only first instance when using replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967119/why-does-javascript-replace-only-first-instance-when-using-replace). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2750xoke/

Answer (score 1):

change

```
replace('_', ' ')
```

to

```
replace(/_/g, ' ')
```