# Alert an array string with .replace

Tags: javascript

Why if i print an array (converted to a string) the .replace function works only on the first `,`?

```js
var messages = ["a", "b", "c"];

alert(messages.toString().replace(',',''));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967119

Comment: Sidenote: in this case you can do the same with: `messages.join('')`

Answer (score 3):

That is how `.replace()` works, it only replaces the first match.

To replace all matches, simply use regex

`.replace(/,/g, '')` the `g` means global, and tells replace to look for ALL matches. The `/` are regex syntax. Learn more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all the occurance, you have to use the global replace

```
/,/g
```

So

```
alert(messages.toString().replace( /,/g,''));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mn93pxth/1/

Comment: 91k rep and you don't know that you shouldn't post code examples to 3rd party sites instead of just putting a code snippet into your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what passing a string to replace does. Using a regular expression with the global `g` flag solves it.

```js
var messages = ["a", "b", "c"];

alert(messages.toString().replace(/,+/g,''));
```