# Replacing each instance of option value , not working for me

Tags: jquery

I have a value like this

```
<option value="RB+TE+WR+DEF+CB">text</option>
```

I'm trying to replace all instances of "+" with a "-"

Both my tries only replaced the 1st "+" and results were

```
<option value="RB-TE+WR+DEF+CB">text</option>
```

This is what i've tried

```
$('option').each(function () {
    $(this).val(function (i, v) {
        return v.replace("+", "-");
    });
})

$('option').val(function (i, v) {
    return v.replace("+", "-");
});

$('option').val(function (i, v) {
    return v.replace(new RegExp("/+/", "g"), '-');
});
```

I need the result to be

```
<option value="RB-TE-WR-DEF-CB">text</option>
```

Comment: try looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967121/2943218

Comment: tried that as well

Comment: Have you tried to use `replaceAll()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `+` in regular expressions.

```
$('option').val(function (i, v) {
    return v.replace(/\+/g, "-");
});
```

or [use `.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) ([does not work in IE](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_replaceall))

```
$('option').val((i, v) => v.replaceAll("+", "-"));
```